# Getting video stream from different pages WebRTC

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

Can we get all the video stream of peers on one page, and peer would be streaming it from any other page. The diagram explain the rest
[graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZSYe.png)

Answer (score 0):

When developing a web application, your code lives inside it's own special little sandbox. This sandbox does not extend to other pages and sharing resources between tabs is therefore impossible.